# Single destination shortest-path in a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

Given a graph and a destination node, how do you find all the shortest paths from all other vertices to the destination vertex.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846836/the-best-shortest-path-algoritm

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Dijkstra's algorithm. You can work it backwards as if your destination is your starting vertex. This will give you the distance and path to any other node.

*PS: Just one thing to remember. You need to reverse the edges BEFORE applying Dijkstra with your destination as your starting vertex in order for that to work.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's bi-directional, you could just start at the destination and work your way outwards. This is commonly known as a Breadth First Search (BFS).

Anything linking to dest has a distance of 1. Anything linking to any of those nodes (that aren't already counted) has a distance of  2. Repeat until you're out of nodes.

Even if it wasn't bidrectional, you could still do this quite easily by "faking" its bidirectionalism with a single pass through the nodes to start with.

In any event, it's order(V + E) to do so, where V is your number of nodes and E is your number of edges.

Comment: This is not likely to get him what he wants. He wants a path from any node to a destination node.

Comment: @nik obviously, you're storing the path as you go along. I should have mentioned that explicitly. @Davin this is a BFS. You can (trivially) adapt it to account for weight edges by placing the acquired nodes in a priority queue and using a greedy algorithm, comparing reached nodes to check if their distance to root plus distance there is less than current distance to root.

Comment: Should have written BFS in the answer, it wasn't very clear from the description. And the running time is linear, which is O(V+E), not sure what `n` is in your answer. Not sure that I understand that "adaption" to account for weighted edges; I don't know of any algorithms that run in linear time and solve the shortest path problem, especially not BFS!

Comment: @davin you're correct that the adaptation, while trivial in terms of implementation, has a drastic effect on the running time. Thanks for the clarification on the `O(V+E)`. I have revised the post appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Dijkstra's algorithm is good if you have weighted edges and want to minimize the total cost of the weights on the path, but in an unweighted graph (all edges have the same cost), a simple breadth-first search will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Just in order to complete the most helpful answer above.

In order for that solution to work, you need to reverse the edges of the graph before applying Dijkstra with your destination as your starting vertex.