# Shortest Path Algorithm With Updates

Tags: java, algorithm, shortest-path

There are N cities and there are M bidirectional roads connected to them , I have to find the shortest path between two fixed cities A and B.

But the problem is there are Q queries given such that path between two cities is blocked , i have to find the shortest path in each Q queries.

My time Complexity in my brute force Algorithm is O(QNlogN) which give me Time Limit Exceeded Error, How can i improve my solution please Help

**Pseduo Code:**

```
for u in Q:
  cin>>a>>b;
graph[a][b] = graph[b][a] = INFINITY VALUE
dijkstra algorithm();
cout<<Distance[D]<<endl;
```

[Problem LINK](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/going-office)

[MY CODE Which Is giving me Time Limit Exceeded Error](http://ideone.com/vGycl1) 
Plese Help How can I improve my algorithm ?

Comment: There are plenty of posts here on this site that cover the Shortest Path or Djikstra's algorithm you should look them up, or go google.

Comment: possible duplicate of [the  best  shortest path algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846836/the-best-shortest-path-algorithm)

Comment: @DavidColer his time complexity shows that he is using Dijkstra's algorithm

Comment: @DavidColer   please read the question carefully , it's is not about shortes path it's about how to Djikstra algorithm effect if one path is blocked

Comment: @PhamTrung yes but my question is little different please read it carefully

Answer (score 3):

The paper [Vickrey Prices and Shortest Paths:
What is an edge worth? by John Hershberger and Subhash Suri](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~parkes/cs286r/spring02/papers/vickrey.pdf) shows how to solve this problem in time O(NlogN+M) where N is the number of vertices, and M is the number of edges.

This allows you to precalculate the M answers depending on which road is blocked, so you can answer each query in O(1), for a total complexity of O(NlogN+M+Q).