# which is the best algorithm(time complexity) to find the shortest path

Tags: c#, asp.net, algorithm, graph-algorithm, dijkstra

I have an
[adjacency matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjeyR.jpg) . I have to calculate shortest + alternate path:

1. from one vertex (A) to another vertex (B)
2. from all vertices to single vertex
3. of a pair of vertices
4. from every vertex every other vertex

I have to calculate all these using graph algorithms (dijkstra, BellManford, BFS). Can anyone suggest me which will be the best* algorithm to implement these.

*best means least time; complexity

Comment: How do you define "best"?

Comment: best means least time complexity

Comment: 1 and 3 appear redundant, no?

Comment: yes.. they are almost same

Comment: There should be complexity considerations on all of those algorithms all over the the internet. But if your implementation is really time critical, you'll have to do performance measures with your real world data.

Comment: i need some hint( suggestion) about the implementation. can each bulleted question be implemented using single algorithm. or each question should be implemented using different algorithm to reduce time complexity

Comment: Please refer my answer for comparison between algorithms: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77511290/5745574

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends heavily on your data. Wikipedia has a [pretty good overview](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem) of the different algorithms that are available, as well as some clues as to when these are useful. An important factor is whether you can place some restrictions on the weights of the edges. The basic breakdown is generally as follows:

#### Identical, positive weights

If all weights are the same and positive, we essentially want to find the path using the smallest number of edges. In this case we can use breadth- or depth-first search to find the single-source shortest paths in O(E + V) time. This is then straightforwardly extended to all-pairs in O(EV + V<sup>2</sup>) time.

#### Non-negative edge weights

For the single-source shortest path problem, you can use [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm). With a normal binary heap, this gives you a time complexity of O((E + V) log V). With a Fibonacci heap, this can be improved to O(E + V log V), which is faster for dense graphs.

Alternatively, there is Gabow's scaling algorithm, which has a running time of O(E log<sub>R</sub> L) time, where R is E/V and L is the maximum length of an edge, but this algorithm is quite a bit more complicated than Dijkstra's.

For finding the shortest path between one pair of vertices, you may be able to use the [A* algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) (or one of its derivatives), but this is contingent on the availability of a suitable heuristic.

#### Negative edge weights, but no negative cycles

Single-source shortest path is solved by the [Bellman-Ford algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm), with a time complexity of O(VE).

All-pairs shortest path can be solved using [Johnson's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson's_algorithm) in O(EV + V<sup>2</sup> log V) time. Additionally, there is the [Floyd-Warshall algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm), which solves it in O(V<sup>3</sup>): this is typically faster on dense graphs.

Comment: Please refer my answer for comparison between algorithms: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77511290/5745574