# Pathfinding with waypoints in any order

Tags: algorithm, path-finding

- I have a list of waypoints(list of 2d-points) in a 2d-area.
- I want the shortest path to visit any waypoint at least one time.
- The order of visiting **does not matter**

Do I have to bruteforce that?

- Calculate distances between all points
- Walk through **any** path.
- return the shortest

Comment: Unclear what you mean by ‘any’ but here are some ideas on shortest path(s): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846836/the-best-shortest-path-algorithm

Comment: I have a list of waypoints and i want the shortest path to visit them all at least one time

Comment: Each waypoint = an Euler Tour. Start with Euler Tour / Path https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path and look for shortest tour algorithms. Also the Travelling Salesman problem https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is a variant of [Hamiltonian Path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) / [Traveling Salesman Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem).

These problem are NP-Complete, but if the number of "waypoints" is relatively small, you can brute-force your way to solve it, after some preprocessing is done.

First, create a new graph:

```
G'=(V',E', w') Where
V' = {v | v is a waypoint }
E' = { (u,v) for all u,v in V' }
w'(u,v) = D(u,v) (where D is a function for shortest path between waypoints in the original graph) (D:VxV->R)
```

You can create w' by using an all to all shortest path algorithm, such as [Floyd-Warshall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm). This is done in `O(|V|^3)`.

After you have it, run a brute force (`O(n!)`, where `n` is the number of waypoints) or Dynamic Programming (`O(2^n*n)`), to solve the Traveling Salesman Problem you have.